# How to put an accent mark on a barred i (U+0268) without the tittle/dot

Tags: tipa

I’m writing a linguistics paper using the `tipa` package, and I need to put an acute accent mark (`´`) to show tone on top of a barred i (`ɨ`). If I use `\'{\textbari}` or `textipa{\'1}` I get a character with the accent mark on top of the tittle. However, I need it to remove the tittle. With a normal `i`, I could just write `\'{\i}` with a backslash in front of it to remove the tittle, but crucially, this doesn’t work for something like `\textbari`.

In short, I get [image], but I need [image].

Grateful for suggestions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems quite enough for the standard sizes.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{pict2e,picture}
\usepackage{color}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\textdotlessbari}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \settowidth\dimen@{\textbari}%
  \makebox[\dimen@]{%
    \sbox\z@{\i}%
    \begin{picture}(0,\ht\z@)
    \roundcap
    \linethickness{0.055ex}
    \put(0.05\wd\z@,0.55\ht\z@){\line(1,0){0.9\wd\z@}}
    \end{picture}%
    #1\i
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textbariacute}{\textdotlessbari{\'}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textbarigrave}{\textdotlessbari{\`}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

--\textbari--

--\textbariacute--

\leavevmode
\rlap{\textcolor{red}{\textbari}}\textbariacute
\rlap{\textcolor{red}{\textbariacute}}\textbari

\textbariacute\textbarigrave\textdotlessbari{\~}

\Huge
--\textbari--

--\textbariacute--

\leavevmode
\rlap{\textcolor{red}{\textbari}}\textbariacute
\rlap{\textcolor{red}{\textbariacute}}\textbari

\textbariacute\textbarigrave\textdotlessbari{\~}

\end{document}
```

The third line shows the characters superimposed to one another in different color and the differences are very small to be really noticeable.

[image]

Comment: I have been using this answer in many papers, but if I wanted to make this available also with \large font size, how would I go about in defining that?

Comment: @Lundgren8 Fixed to work with every size.

Comment: Thanks, that works brilliantly! Is it possible to make this work in a section header? I think it would be very legible, but in theory I could also type out its phonetic definition as a title.

Comment: @Lundgren8 Doesn't it work in a section title?

Comment: Huh, that’s weird. It works when I isolate it in a new document, but within my own project I get ~32 error messages. It must clash with some other package or something.

Comment: @Lundgren8 Note that, as the code stands, only `\textbariacute` and `\textbarigrave` do not pose problems with section titles. If you're using `\textdotlessbari`, change `\newcommand` in `\DeclareRobustCommand` in its definition.

Answer (score 2):

Use `\rlap{-}\'\i` or `\leavevmode\rlap{-}\'\i` if that symbol start a paragraph. Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\leavevmode\rlap{-}\'\i p  ip  \rlap{-}\'\i p ip
\end{document}
```

Comment: ``\makebox[0pt][l]{-}\'i`` would be my choice